# How obtain path of IP address

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I would like obtain `path[2]` of IP-address using regexp. It's useful for authentication access control.

```
var a = "10.56.7.234";
var x = /\d+\.(\d+)\./;
WScript.Echo(a.replace(x,"")+" split "+a.split(x)[0]+";"+a.split(x )[1]);
```

How to set x for obtain 56 as result?

What about `((new Regex("(\\d+)")).Match("10.56.7.234")).Value?` Windows 7 generate exception on split.

```
int ip = 
int.TryParse(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].Split('.')[1],out ip) 
? ip : ip;
/* generate exception, and regexp is not generate exception */
```

Comment: `/\d+\.(\d+)\./.exec("10.56.7.234")[1]`

Comment: What about simple split: `"10.56.7.234".split('.')[1]`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  thanks, I do not undestand why replace and split isn't give result, but exec  obtain good result. I have question: Сan regexp get result from any label to any label, for example only number number 2 of IP address?

Comment: You need to specify the context for each number, or you will get the first one. In your case, use `split(".")`, it is easier.

Comment: One of variant  string s=(((new Regex(@"\.(\d+\.)")).Match("10.23.45.678"))).ToString()  gets .23.

Comment: Can be simply regexp? int ip = int.Parse("0" + (((new Regex(@"\.(\d+\.)")).Match(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]))).ToString().Replace(".", ""));

Answer (score 0):

You must implement it using regex?

One alternative would be:

```
var a = "10.56.7.234";
var b = a.split(".");
var x = b[1];
```

Comment: Split generate array, I whold like one-way simple expression that obtain answer in c#. When IP-address is bad I have exception.